# Does IPC guarantee message order in Linux?

Tags: protocols, ipc, zeromq

I need to create a monitor, which will log information about packet missing using ZeroMQ ipc. Actually I don't really understand everything about it because of there are some LINX, TIPS protocols also. Can you please explain me that and answer the main question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the application self-monitoring, by including a message serial number in each message structure. The message sender keeps track of the serial number it last sent, and increments it every time it sends a message.

The recipient should then be receiving messages with ever-increasing message serial numbers embedded. If that ever jumps by 2 or more, a message has gone missing.

IPC is not lossy like a network can be - the bytes put in come out the other end. TCP is not lossy either, provided both ends are still running and the network itself hasn't failed. However, depending on the ZMQ pattern used and how it's set up whole messages can be undelivered (for example, if the recipient hasn't connected yet, etc). If that's what you mean by "packet missing", it would be revealed by including an incrementing message serial number.